# How can I cast inside a case statement SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, case

I am trying to change the value NULL to the string 'geen boetes' (Dutch for 'no fines') but it doesn't let me because I can't save a string in a numeric value type. I Tries every possible way to put CAST in there but I can't find the solution. Does anyone know what I do wrong?

```
SELECT CAST(s.naam AS varchar)
FROM spelers s;


SELECT 
    s.naam, 
    CASE    
        WHEN AVG(b.bedrag) IS NOT NULL 
            THEN ROUND(avg(b.bedrag), 2)
            ELSE CAST(AVG(b.bedrag) AS varchar) IS NULL THEN 0
    END as gemiddelde
FROM 
    spelers s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    boetes b ON s.spelersnr = b.spelersnr
GROUP BY 
    s.naam
ORDER BY 
    s.naam
```

I tried to use the cast command to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an expression that returns a numeric value under some conditions and a string value under other conditions, the expression must always return the same type. The *solution* in the case is casting the avg.

```
select 
    s.naam, 
    case    
        when avg(b.bedrag) is not null 
            then cast(round(avg(b.bedrag), 2) as varchar) 
            else 'geen boetes' 
    end as gemiddelde
from 
    spelers s 
left outer join 
    boetes b on s.spelersnr = b.spelersnr
group by 
    s.naam
order by 
    s.naam
```

Comment: Then my time was well spent.